# The best way to convert array elements as keys in a new dictionary

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary

What is the best way to convert array elements as keys in a new dictionary ?

Comment: To create a Dictionary (or probably rather HashMap) in Java, you will need both keys and values. Map keys are created when you put a value in the Map with the associated key. Could you give some more detail on what you really need to do?

Answer (score 4):

This isn't much to go on, but let's see:

Say you have an `int[10]` and you want to store them in a `HashMap` (Dictionaries aren't used much these days). You could do this:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> dict = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    dict.put(i,array[i]); // autoboxing takes care of primitives
}
```

If you were looking to use the actual values in the array as the keys in the dictionary, then you have to ask yourself "Where are my dictionary values coming from?"

For example, if you wanted the values to be the index, you could just reverse the above

```
dict.put(array[i],i);
```

Perhaps you have another array with some values in it.

```
int[] intArray = ...
String[] strArray = ...
Map<Integer, String> dict = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    dict.put(intArray[i], strArray[i]); // autoboxing takes care of primitives
}
```

Simply put, you have a `put` method. The first parameter is going to be the key, the second parameter is going to be the value. As long as you're iterating over the array you'll have your keys; then it's just a matter of deciding what values go in there.

Comment: OP wants array elements to be keys, not values

Comment: @soulcheck it's honestly not much information there - but I added more information in the hopes I've covered all bases.

Answer (score 0):

```
Integer[] keys = {1, 2, 3};
HashMap<Integer, Object> map = new HashMap<Integer, Object>();
Collections.addAll( map.keySet(), keys );
```